# AngularJS - text area text with respect to ngBindHtml

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a text area

```
<textarea placeholder="Answer" ng-model="answer">
</textarea>
```

In this I am displaying answer for a question. This text I need to convert using ng-bind-html. I need html text should display after conversion. Please suggest

Comment: look up `$sce` service. in particular `$sce.trustAsHtml(input)`

Comment: @Donthamsettivbhadrarao do you want to show the html text inside text area? or it should be sanitize? please add more description in your question..I think you are looking for chat type of conversation..

Comment: may be this is what you want http://plnkr.co/edit/kWjsFUiUOhjXb1XVFteS?p=preview

Comment: @pankajparkar I am trying to display after html conversion in text area

Comment: @Donthamsettivbhadrarao you wanted to render html inside textarea?

Comment: @Donthamsettivbhadrarao Tale a look at my update

Comment: ok krishnan. Sure thanks for your update

Answer (score 1):

```
Check this working example of above problem solution
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Shital_D/b9qtj56p/6/

Do following
1. Download angular-sanitize.js
2. code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngSanitize"]);       

app.controller('myController', function($scope,$compile) {
    $scope.html = '<p>Your html code</p>';
});

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
         <p ng-bind-html="html"></p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Is it same as you want ?

Comment: I want same like display in text area

Answer (score 1):

You can use content editable div for this instead of pure textarea.

And if you want full set of features like these in edit mode then use wysiwyg editors something like ckeditor http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: Yes jad-panda. I better go for editor like this. I refereed this. I will use this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out to print text of the html content within the textarea

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('Controller', function($scope, $compile) {
  $scope.answer = "<ul><li>Participate</li><li>Prove your self</li></ul>";
  $scope.answer = angular.element($scope.answer)[0].innerText;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Controller">
    <textarea placeholder="Answer" ng-model="answer"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nidhish Krishnan. I wanna display html code after conversion. Suppose if I have "<ul><li>Participate</li><li>Prove your self</li></ul>". Need to convert to html & display

Comment: or do you want to display only `Participate Prove your self` without html codes

Comment: Html conversion for given answer(text) I want Krishnan

Comment: I wanted to display html text in text area after conversion Krishnan.

Comment: you mean to say that your textarea should contains html tags too

Comment: I wanted to display like editor in text area Krishnan.  If <ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul> it shold display as this plunker http://jsfiddle.net/ne3czttq/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$sce.trustAsHtml` to parse another string as HTML and then bind the resulting value using `ng-bind-html` directive like so...

```js
(function() {
  angular.module('myApp',[]);
  
  angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);
  
  myCtrl.$inject = ['$sce', '$scope', '$log'];
  function myCtrl($sce, $scope, $log) {
    var self = this;
    self.snippet = undefined;    
    self.snippetHtml = undefined;
    
    activate();
    
    function activate() {
      self.snippet = '<ul><li>Hello</li><li>World</li>';
      
    }
    
    $scope.$watch(function() { return self.snippet; }, function(oldVal, newVal) {
      self.snippetHtml= $sce.trustAsHtml(newVal);
    });
    
    
  }
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
  <textarea ng-model="vm.snippet"></textarea>
  <div ng-bind-html="vm.snippetHtml"></div>
</div>
```

As other has suggested... only do this when you are **SURE** that the data you want to display is safe.  Otherwise you'll be opening your app to script injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do this. You need angular sanitizer js. And this my code:

```
 var app = angular.module('ck', ['ngSanitize']);
     app.directive('ckEditor', function() {
     require: '?ngModel',
     link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
        var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);

if (!ngModel) return;

  ck.on('pasteState', function() {
    scope.$apply(function() {
      ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
    });
  });
ngModel.$render = function(value) {
    ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
  };
}


};

});
app.controller("ckController",function($scope){
$scope.myText = "</p>Something is here</p>";
})
```

Now render your textarea as: `<textarea ck-editor ng-model="myData"></textarea>`

Now render your div to hold all the data as: `<p ng-bind-html="myData"></p>`